# Android save EditText and recall it next time the app is opened

Tags: java, android

I have code in which it has an **editText** box and a button. I want to save the text entered in the **textbox** and recall it the next time the app is opened.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText txtLink;
Button btnOpenLink;
String defaultLink;
String secondLink;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    defaultLink = "http://";
    secondLink = ".whatver.com";

    txtLink = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    btnOpenLink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btnOpenLink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String server = txtLink.getText().toString();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(server)){
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,webactivity.class);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(defaultLink+server+secondLink));
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter your server name.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

How can this be accomplished? I have tried numerous things that I have found through google but none have seemed to work right, I know it is something that I am doing most likely, I just can not make it work right.

Comment: you could use sharedpreferences . tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: soooo... what are the numerous things? You need to save the data to a file; either a raw file, or preferences xml file, or sqlite database.

Comment: How can this be accomplished with the above code using sharedpreferences? I tried the above tutorial but it did not work. Any ideas>?

Answer (score 4):

Use the preferences....

## Example

```
SharedPreferences spref = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs_name", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();
editor.putString("myTextViewValue", prefVal); //
editor.commit();
```

and somewhen latter when the app starts again read it back:

## Example:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
String storedPreference = preferences.getStr("myTextViewValue", null);
```

so validate what you store and check if the preference you get is null, that means nothing was stored before...

Comment: Can you put that into the above code because i can not make it work

Comment: I followed the tutorial and have tried the above code but it still is not working, any ideas?